# Disable OutputCache on Development System

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

I use OutputCache in an ASP.net MVC application. As developing with an active OutputCache is not very pleasant I want to disable the OutputCache on the Development Systems (local machines and development server).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A newer duplicate question came up with an interesting answer for the situation when you want to alter some output caching but not all: [use cache profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662424/bypass-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc/4665245#4665245).

Answer (score 19):

It's an old one but...

set this in your web.config under system.web

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
</caching>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be false instead of true?

Comment: @TonyBasallo This really does not work on IIS Express 8.Why so ?

Answer (score 15):

The outputcache in ASP.NET can be enabled and disabled using

For iis versions < 7.0

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

For iis versions >= 7.0

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

N.B. *I usually use both, better safe than having a sore foot, and use a config transform to make sure that the caching is enabled for different configurations on publish. In my solution a configuration corresponds 1 on 1 with an environment*

Another technique is to use pragmas to enable pieces of code to compile or not compile based on i.e. the DEBUG conditional compilation symbol:

```
#if DEBUG
    [OutputCache]
#endif
```

Comment: The pre IIS 7 version is needed for IIS Express 8

Comment: These two examples (pre & post IIS7), are for different functionalities.  

The example in `<system.web>` is for the ASP.NET OutputCache (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/caching/). The example in `<system.webServer>` is for built-in IIS response caching (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/caching/).
IIS cache is interoperable with OutputCache.