# Simple OutputCache is not working in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, caching, .net-4.0, webforms

I have this in my web-form,

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="none" Duration="30"   %>
```

In the page load I have,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

But still with every request it takes more than 5 seconds, means caching is not working? I

Answer (score 1):

check this thread:
[Disable OutputCache on Development System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788376/disable-outputcache-on-development-system)

also if your system is under memory pressure, it may not cache the page or may discard it sooner than anticipated. test on a clean machine.